# Python: Simple lock for responsive UI during IO

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, io

I am writing a simple image viewer program. I have noticed that resizing image takes quite a bit of time, I decided to pre-cache the "new" image while user is still watching the previous one. Simple solution: run it in thread.

I am quite a n00b, both to Python and to programming in general, however I think I have basic concepts covered. I just lack the knowledge to implement thread locking, that's all.

One thing of note: I am using Python for functional, not OO, programming.

The code I have is like that:

```
def prepare_images():
    global prep_photos, prepare_images_flag

    for position in prep_grid.keys():
        widget = root.nametowidget( position )
        try:
            t_ = time.clock()
            photo = Image.open( directory + prep_grid[position] )
            print 'Time opening', time.clock() - t_

            t_ = time.clock()
            my_size = [ widget.winfo_width()-10, widget.winfo_height()-5 ]
            # recalculate size for proper aspect ratio
            if my_size[0]/photo.size[0] > my_size[1]/photo.size[1]:
                my_size[0] = int(photo.size[0] * my_size[1]/photo.size[1])
            else:
                my_size[1] = int(photo.size[1] * my_size[0]/photo.size[0])
            print 'Time calculating', time.clock() - t_
            print my_size

            t_ = time.clock()
            tmp_photo = photo.resize( my_size, Image.ANTIALIAS )
            print 'Time resizing', time.clock() - t_

            t_ = time.clock()
            prep_photos[position] = ImageTk.PhotoImage( tmp_photo )
            print 'Time preparing', time.clock() - t_

        except Exception, e:
            print Exception, e
            pass

    prepare_images_flag = 1

def select_image(event):
    global current_grid, current_photos, prepare_images_flag
    while prepare_images_flag != 1:
        print "Waiting for image processing..."
        time.sleep(0.5)
    current_grid = prep_grid.copy()
    current_photos = prep_photos.copy()
    show_images()
    grid_init()
    prepare_images_flag=0
    Thread(target=prepare_images, args=[]).start()
```

What you'll notice is that I tried to use a global variable as a flag, only to learn that functions actually get local copy that is not updated in the other function (I know, naive, but it was worth a shot :-) ).

The problem for me is that all the usage examples I found are either for spawning 10's of threads and syncing them inbetween, or use OO-approach - I believe there is a way to have select_image() function wait until prepare_images() reports it's done with the job that doesn't include a total rewrite of my app.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: _"I tried to use a global variable as a flag, only to learn that functions actually get local copy that is not updated in the other function"_. That doesn't sound right. The entire point of global variables is, if you modify it in one function, that change will be visible in any other function, even across threads.

Comment: @Kevin that's not entirely true.  The variable needs to be ["locked"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4744654/447015) in order to be properly accessed.

Comment: @KronoS - I think this is exactly what I'm asking about: how can I do that?

Comment: Guys, it's getting better every day. Initially I used 'while prepare_images_flag != 1:' as a simple flag - as I said, it locked my program if "select_image" event happened while "prepare_images" thread was still running.
So I tried with threading.Lock() and "with lock:". Same thing happened: main thread stopped at "with lock:" line, while "prepare images" stopped at whatever point it was atm.
So I tried again with threading.Event(). Same. Fraking. Thing. The main thread locks on "event.wait()"; the other thread stops executing, and in effect never does "event.set()".
Guys, what's up in here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally found the solution (and why this didn't work well at the beginning).

Turns out TkInter doesn't really like other threads - if I use Tkinter to service an event, for example, it will stop execution of other threads (learn it by using this gem: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577334-how-to-debug-deadlocked-multi-threaded-programs/ ).

I solved this issue by moving nearly all of event code into separate thread. See below (select_image is the function pinned to a Tkinter widget):

```
def prepare_images():
    global image_prepare_lock
    thread_table = {}

    with image_prepare_lock:
        if root.winfo_width()-10 <= 0 or root.winfo_height()-10 <= 0:
            width = 10
            height = 10
        else:
            width = root.winfo_width()//2
            height = root.winfo_height()//2-10

        dimensions = [ width, height ]

        for position in prep_grid:
            # Open images here so that threads don't fight for disk access
            prep_grid[position]['photo_raw'] = Image.open( directory + prep_grid[position]['name'] )
            thread_table[position] = Thread(target=prepare_single_image, args=[position, dimensions])
            thread_table[position].start()

        # wait for all children threads to finish
        for position in prep_grid:
            thread_table[position].join()
            prep_grid[position]['photo_tkinter'] = ImageTk.PhotoImage( prep_grid[position]['photo_resized'] )

        root.nametowidget(".title").config(text="Compare photos", bg="green", fg="white")

def prepare_single_image(position, dimensions):
    global prep_grid

    prep_grid[position]['hash'] = hashlib.md5(prep_grid[position]['photo_raw'].tostring()).hexdigest()
    prep_grid[position]['photo_resized'] = prep_grid[position]['photo_raw'].copy()
    prep_grid[position]['photo_resized'].thumbnail( dimensions, Image.ANTIALIAS )

def select_image(event):
    Thread(target=cycle_images, args=[event]).start()

def cycle_images(event):
    global current_grid
    global image_prepare_lock

    with image_prepare_lock:
        current_grid = prep_grid.copy()
        show_images()
        grid_init()

        Thread(target=prepare_images, args=[]).start()
```

Let me know if anyone has any questions.